# Algorithm to check if a given graph is valid

Tags: algorithm, graph

There are some undirected graphs without loops. The nodes of these graphs are representing income spans of different people, but are undefined. Now, every person in the same income range within this graph should be connected.
The task is that we need to check if the given graphs are valid or not- or more precisely: If there are income spans that are suitable for the nodes in the graph.

Is there any algorithm which is suitable for this case ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your problem is a little vague. Should the **only** edges be those that connect persons in the same income range? How is "income range" related to "income spans"? Are they synonyms? Are spans/ranges always either identical or disjoint? If not, how would you treat two people, one with span [A,B] and the other with span [C,D] where A < C < D < B (one span contained in another)? How about A < C < B < D (overlapping, non-identical spans)?

Comment: It sounds as though you want to recognize [interval graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph).

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad description of the problem.
1. Yes- edges do only appear if the income of two people is inside the same income span. 
2. They are synonyms 
3. It is not important if a span is overlapping or contains another span. Moreover it is already enough if one number inside the spans is the same
Thanks again for your fast reply :)

Comment: _"we need to check...if there are income spans that are suitable for the nodes in the graph."_ So is the problem to assign some interval to each node such that each graph is a valid interval graph, or report failure if such an assignment is impossible? Are there any constraints between nodes or edges in different graphs (that is, if the problem can be solved for a single graph, is that enough)?

Comment: No there aren't. It only needs to solve the problem for every graph seperately.

Comment: Then David's comment above is exactly right. The Wikipedia page has pointers to algorithms for recognizing whether a graph is an interval graph. (Assigning a set of intervals can be done as a byproduct of the recognition itself.)

Comment: Thank you very much Ted and Dadvid!
I am now doing some research on this and it seems like it this is exactly what I was looking for.